# Intel Edison Program Deleted After Power Off

Tags: edison

I just bought a new Intel Edison and flashed the newest Yocto 3.0 image. I uploaded an Arduino program from the Arduino ide which just constantly prints out numbers to serial.

After uploading the code, it works. After I unplug it and plug it back in and wait 2 minutes for it to power on, I open the serial connection and the Edison does nothing like I never uploaded anything.

After some research I found it is a problem with the firmware version 2.5 so I tried 2.1. I tried 2.1 and it still doesn't work. Am I doing anything wrong?

I am using the mini-breakout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a bunch of problems like this.  I went back to 2.1, and that works, but your sketch can't have any code that uses Serial.  Serial1 is fine, but not Serial, or else the board hangs and your sketch won't autorun when you aren't connected via USB during reset.